# how to open/change config file of tvmobili in terminal

Tags: 11.04, configuration, gedit, mediaserver

I must make some changes in my config file for my media server;
tvmobili but I don't know where to find it, what commands must I use?

Comment: Could you please add in some more specific information about what you want to change? Makes it easier to give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `/etc/TVMOBiLi/instances/<instance>/conf/tvMobiliService.conf` for the configuration command line file. Once you have edited this file you will need to restart the service.

[localhost:30888/__index](http://localhost:30888/__index) will also get you directly to configuration if you are on the system that has `TV Mobili` installed.

If you are on a different computer to the one you installed `TV Mobili` onto you can access your installation through [the following page](http://www.tvmobili.com/watch.php). You should see a list of computers on that page, click on the computer that you wish to configure.

`Tv Mobili` also has it own [support forum](http://forum.tvmobili.com/) so you might get better answers there.

Comment: Linux (Desktops and embedded devices)
Open the config file in your editor and add entries for either RunAsUser and/or RunAsGroup. You can set either of these to the user/group id or user/group name. For example:
RunAsUser=500
RunAsGroup=media

Comment: this is from my index page of tvmobili, because i have an alert message on my interface.